# Do you recommend (to me)

Tags: prepositional-phrases, subjunctives

Which sentence is best in english ?

**Context:** I'm asking a question to a friend about what I should take with me for my next holiday.

1. Do you recommend **to take warm clothes**?
2. Do you recommend **to take warm clothes to me**?
3. Do you recommend **to me to take warm clothes**?

Comment: Personally, I'd say, "**Do you recommend that I bring warm clothes (with me)?**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have your questions written is actually a little bit wrong and not natural at all. But I can think of two possible ways to phrase this type of question:

1:

> Do you recommend I take warm clothes with me?

or

> Do you recommend that I take warm clothes with me?

2:

> Would you recommend taking warm clothes with me?

The grammatical patterns of the two sentences are as follows:

1. do you recommend (that) I do something? (recommend (that) someone do something)
2. would you recommend doing something? (recommend doing something)

A bunch of other examples:

Example #1 (pattern #1):

> I **recommend** you **go** and **see** the dentist right now or it might be too late and you will lose your tooth.

Example #2 (pattern #1):

> I **recommend** she **call** her parents right now or she'll be in real trouble!

Example #3 (pattern #2):

> I would **recommend watching** the explanation video first because that way you will get the understanding down first and be ready to tackle the exercises.

Example #4 (pattern #2)

> — Which hat would you **recommend buying**?
>   — I'd buy this one.

P.S.

You might be wondering why in pattern #1 the second verb doesn't end in s. That's called [the subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English). Subjunctive structures in English do not require that. They always go with bare infinitives. *recommend* is one of those verbs that almost always intrinsically has that subjunctive sense to it.

---

As for the question, this is how I personally would say it:

> Do you think I should take warm clothes with me?

Comment: There are more like *it's important she call her parents*, *it's necessary she call her parents* or by using *it's important for she to call her parents.*

Comment: If the recommendation is about something and not a actionm is it ok to say:
Can you recommend me a book to read?

Comment: "Can you recommend me a good book to read?" -- that sounds fine.